# Need to resize UIImageView only from the top side?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios9

I have some rectangle of type UIImageView which is subclassed (Rectangle:UIImageView) class. What I'm trying to do is, when touchesBegan or when touchesMoved I need to resize ONLY the top position of it, while the bottom must to stay fixed in its place, but I'm having some problems. The thing is, it's resizing, but from the bottom side, instead of the top. I've tried changing the anchor point but no luck. It seems like the UIImageView anchor point stays the same and it's resizing from the bottom. How to fix this?

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {

 if let touch = touches.first
    {
        let position = touch.locationInView(self.superview)
        if CGRectContainsPoint((self.superview?.frame)!, position)
        {

        self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: 

self.frame.origin.y, width: self.frame.width, height: position.y)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: If the image view (`self`) is originally positioned using auto layout, trying to change its `frame` is not going to work...

Comment: @matt What will you suggest me to do matt?

Comment: I suggest you tell him whether you are using autolayout or not.

Comment: @YuchenZhong Hey bro. The thing is, yes, I do have autolayout, and I managed to change the size based on the topConstraint programatically rather than changing the frame of it. But I'm having an issue on how to synchronize the property of the topConstraint based on my touch input to correspond correctly when touches will begin. So far, Wingzero gave me some good suggestions and I'm on the right track. But I'm stucked onto the last one, still figuring out. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Count you show a screenshot of your current constraints that you are using? And a screenshot of your current current look of the button when you pressed the button (if this is possible)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change from the top side, you should change origin.y, and accordingly calculate a proper hight based on what you needs.

```
    self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: self.frame.origin.y, 
                        width: self.frame.width, height: position.y)
```

Your code above will only change its height, and keeps it's origin point the same, that's why you see it moves from bottom to top

as matt said, if you are using auto layout, then you should change constraints to move the view ranther than changing frame.

Update:
since you are using auto layout, then a simple way is you control-drag the top space constraint to your .m file as a property, let's say it's called `topSpaceContraint`, and at run time, to change it like

`topSpaceConstraint.constant = {WHAT EVER YOU WANT}`

if you want to animate it, call `imageView.layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block

Comment: I set up this object in the Main.storyboard, indeed i've set up some constraints of it. What do I need to do in order to change the anchor point? Can I do it while initializing the object somehow within the init method of the class or within the ViewController? Any guidelines?

Comment: I totally understand you now bro. And one more thing, how do I synchronize the topConstraint based on my touch input to have a happy resizable image with a moveable constraint at the end? :D

Comment: You can add the image view's height constraint as well. so you can change both of them at the same time.

Comment: I don't have any height constraints, I have only aspect ratio constraint, top, bottom and horizontal center assigned. If I put a height constraints I have to modify it based on a different devices for the screen when first time loading up cos it will appear smaller on some or bigger on the other devices I think. :( Can't I do it somehow with the top constraint to hook up proportionally with the touch input changes?

Comment: first you should figure out the start frame and end frame. then use this end frame to calculate the corresponding constraints you have.